# Using PluralizationService class in dotnetfiddle

Tags: c#, .net-fiddle

I want to do some tests with the class [PluralizationService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice(v=vs.110).aspx) using dotnetfiddle.net but I get an error:

> The type of namespace name 'Design' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity'

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

[link to the example in dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jrEtpS)

I've tried adding a reference to EntityFramework (in the NuGet Packages section) but this has not worked.  Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Comment: You need a reference to `System.Data.Entity.Design` to use this, not sure you can do that with dotnetfiddle website. Try downloading LinqPad instead, that will let you do references to anything you like (and it's awesome)

Comment: Yes, maybe dotnetfiddle just does not allow to add a reference to some namespaces. I just want to be sure that I'm not missing something.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't add a reference to a namespace, you reference a specific DLL. That DLL will contain at least one namespace. The namespace you want (`System.Data.Entity.Design`) is in a DLL by the same name which is in the GAC.

Comment: dotnetfiddle won't allow adding references. it can only add nuget packages and System.Data.Entity.Design isn't nuget package, so it can't be added there

Comment: Thanks for your answers.   
I just want to add a reference to a namespace ([Using Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx)).  This is possible in dotnetfiddle. For example if you want to use List<int> you need to add a reference to System.Collections.Generic.

Comment: Correct, but if you are adding namespace that is located in different assembly that isn't added to the project (like System.Data.Entity.Design), then this assembly needs to be added to project too. And .NetFiddle doesn't allow it due to security problems

Comment: It seems like dotnetfiddle adds some assemblies by default, example: system.core.dll (using system.Linq;), mscorlib.dll (using system.Globalization;). But if you need some namespace that belongs to an assembly that it hasn't been added, you can't do anything.

Comment: Yes, correct. we don't add anything except default list. And all others assemblies can be added just as nuget packages.